# Name for the universal normed space associated to a seminormed space

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, category-theory, terminology, normed-spaces

If $(V,p)$ is a seminormed space, then $(V/N,\overline{p})$ is a normed space, where $N=\{x \in V : p(x)=0\}$ and $\overline{p}(x \bmod N) = p(x)$. My question is as follows: Is there a **common name** for this normed space? It is the universal normed space equipped with a short linear map from $(V,p)$, but it would be nice to have a short name. Note that on the induced topological spaces  this construction is the maximal Hausdorff quotient, or Hausdorffication.

Comment: I'd simply call it the Kolmogorov quotient, but I'm not actually sure how widespread that term is.

Comment: Ok, this is because T0-spaces are also known as Kolmogorov spaces, and for topological groups, T0,T1,T2 are equivalent.

Comment: Yes, and it goes far beyond T2 in this case, so sticking to T0 makes sense, especially since this is how T0-ification is always done ("just paste the points that are obviously indistinguishable"), unlike the construction of eg. Hausdorff or Tychonoff reflection in general. Unfortunately it doesn't seem to be a popular term, although I like it exactly for these (frequent) kinds of situations (turning the seminorm into norm or pseudometric into metric).